# How do I create the amazon s3 url in a way that allows my deployment target to download a file created by the build stage using SSM runCommmand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a pipeline, which creates an artifact in the build stage. For this artifact I have the `bucketName` the `objectKey` as well as some

```
{
    "accessKeyId": "...",
    "secretAccessKey": "...",
    "sessionToken": "...",
    "expirationTime": 1670840680000
}
```

As I cannot install the deployment agent on the instance I want to deploy to, I need to use wget for fetching the artifact from s3.

I struggle to find out how to construct the url correctly as I always get `403`s

So my question would be:

How do I create the s3 download url in a way that allows my deployment target to download the file that is created by the build stage?

Answer (score 0):

S3 URLs generally follow the pattern `https://bucket-name.s3.region-code.amazonaws.com/key-name`. See this page for more details and alternatives - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html

Note that you will not be able to access an object in S3 with wget unless it's public. If you must use wget for a non-public object, you will need to do so via a presigned URL.

Alternatively you could use the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-copy) to fetch the file.

Comment: Thanbks for your answer, you are right of course.. unfortunately, I cannot use aws cli on the targeted VMs either ;)

Answer (score 0):

OMG.. It was such a n00b mistake :D

I used a too short `expires-in``

```js
  const node = new AWS.SSM({
  });
  const preSignedUrl = (new AWS.S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    credentials: artifactCredentials
  }).getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: inputArtifactsS3Location.bucketName,
    Key: inputArtifactsS3Location.objectKey,
    Expires: 604800
  }))
```

This snipped generate the right url now.. of course 604800 is bit too high now.. who ever finds this.. tune it to an appropriate level for you